# Заменить текст между тегами в верхний регистр в PHP

Tags: php, php7

Хочу сделать текст в верхнем регистре между тегами h2, но почему то следующий код не работает:

```
<?php
$str = '<h2>Марина</h2> <b>Алёша</b> случайный текст <h2>Наташа</h2> <h2>Катя</h2>';

$str = preg_replace_callback('|<h2>(.+)</h2>|iU', function($matches){
    $upper = strtoupper($matches[1]);
    return '<h2>'. $upper .'</h2>';
}, $str);

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замени `<h2>(.+)</h2>` на `<h2>(.*?)<\/h2>`

Comment: Заменил, все равно не работает

Comment: Немного по эксперементировал понял:
1. выражения "|<h2>(.*?)<\/h2>|" вполне хватит чтобы найти буковки
2. strtoupper не работает с кирилицей
3. mb_strtoupper($matches[1], "utf-8") вместо strtoupper, но нужно что бы был включен модуль php mbstring

Comment: Да, действительно, проблема была в "strtoupper не работает с кирилицей". Спасибо